# Detect Russian / cyrillic in Javascript string?

Tags: javascript, regex, encoding, cyrillic

I'm trying to detect if a string contains Russian (cyrillic) characters or not. I'm using this code:

```
term.match(/[\wа-я]+/ig);
```

but it doesn't work – or in fact it just returns the string back as it is.

Can somebody help with the right code?

Thanks!

Comment: You include `\w` in the regular expression, so it matches words with Latin characters as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to use the `RegExp` `test` method instead?

```
/[а-яА-ЯЁё]/.test(term)
```

Note that JavaScript regexes are not really Unicode-aware, which means the `i` flag will have no effect on anything that's not ASCII. Hence the need for spelling out lower- and upper-case ranges separately.

Comment: You might want to add `Ёё` since they are also used in Russian.

Comment: the cyrillic unicode range doens't work, but the other method works great

Comment: This answers means you have to store your .js files as unicode. Hmm.

Comment: @cymro, or use Unicode escape within the regex. But storing and transmitting text files as UTF-8 should really be the default nowadays. We're not in the 70s anymore.

Comment: Joey, thanks for your comment. Storing js files as UTF-8 often adds an unwanted BOM at the beginning.

Answer (score 41):

Use pattern [`/[\u0400-\u04FF]/`](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF) to cover more cyrillic characters:

```js
// http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF
const cyrillicPattern = /^[\u0400-\u04FF]+$/;

console.log('Привіт:', cyrillicPattern.test('Привіт'));
console.log('Hello:', cyrillicPattern.test('Hello'));
```

UPDATE:

In [some new browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_property_escapes), you can use [Unicode property escapes](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes).

The Cyrillic script [uses](https://2ality.com/2017/07/regexp-unicode-property-escapes.html#examples-of-properties) the same range as described above: `U+0400..U+04FF`

```js
const cyrillicPattern = /^\p{Script=Cyrillic}+$/u;

console.log('Привіт:', cyrillicPattern.test('Привіт'));
console.log('Hello:', cyrillicPattern.test('Hello'));
```

Comment: Perfect answer! More character ranges can be found in this format here: http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block

Comment: @hyperknot Link is not available anymore

Comment: @emvaized I cannot update my comment but here is the link from Archive.org:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200118100606/http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block

Comment: No spaces or punctuation are working