# How to block Cyrillic unicode by jQuery on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, spam

In my website, I'm receiving some subscriptions spam. All of them is from people which type their names using Russian alphabet.

I know that in this case the most recommended thing to do is put a captcha in my subscription page form. But, as this case is so specific, and at the same time I don't want to affect my real customers experience, in a first time I would like to have a jQuery script which deny the form submit when detects Russian alphabet in some input. Can some one help me with it? (Or is better do it using PHP?)

[Simple form exemple](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EegzQJ)

```
<form action="#" id="form-validate">
  <input type="text" class="input" id="firstname">
  <button class="submit">teste</button>
</form>
```

To be more specific. For example, a script that detects a Cyrillic character in the input string, such as: "John Потоцкая Doe", and then avoid the form submit.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please provide the community with a minimal, verifiable example (the relevant part of your code) in the body of your question in order for us to assist you better.

Comment: @esqew, for exemple in this simple form: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EegzQJ - I would like a jQuery script that detects if in the input has some Cyrillic characters, for exemple: "John Потоцкая Doe" And if has, block on form submit. Got it?

Comment: It's not a good idea to detect spam on the client-side in browser. A human may switch Javascript off and submit a form. Moreover spam bots often skip Javascript at all, they will simply not notice your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a Regex range that hits all the Cyrillic unicode ranges:

```
let pattern  /[\u0400-\u04FF]/;
if (pattern.test("John Потоцкая Doe")) console.log("cyrillic");
else console.log("not cyrillic");
```

<sup>[Relevant SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846663/detect-russian-cyrillic-in-javascript-string)</sup>

Your code will end up looking like this:

```js
let pattern = /[\u0400-\u04FF]/;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form-validate').submit(function() {
    if (pattern.test($('input#firstname').val())) { //If "input" contains a Cyrillic character...
      alert('Invalid input: please use Latin characters only.'); // pop alert message
      $('input#firstname').val("") // empty field of invalid contents
      return false; // prevent form from submitting
    } else
      return true; // allow form to be submitted
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="form-validate">
  <input type="text" class="input" id="firstname">
  <button class="submit">teste</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello @esqew. Thank you again! Can you help me to adapts your solution to this code? codepen.io/anon/pen/EegzQJ

Comment: Maybe this base could be better to we work on: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLbWPz

Comment: Oh that's it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could see where Cyrillic characters live in the Unicode space here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode

Then loop through character by character to see if any character falls in that range, something like:

```
let str = 'Україна';
let cyrillic = false;
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str.codePointAt(i) >= 0x0400 && str.codePointAt(i) <= 0x052f) {
    cyrillic = true;
  }
}
```

There may be an easier way with regexes, e.g. range `/[A-Za-z]/` gives Latin letters, may be something similar for general Unicode code points.

**Edit**

This might be slightly cleaner with ES5 Array prototype methods, e.g. one-liner would be:

```
let cyrillic = str.split('').some(char => char.codePointAt(0) >= 0x0400 && char.codePointAt(0) <= 0x052f);
```

Comment: Hi, @jpsimons. Thanks for your response. So, in this case, how this snippet would avoid a form submit which has, for exemple, the follow string: "John Потоцкая Doe"? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EegzQJ - Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Maybe this base could be better to we work on: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLbWPz